# Move docker setup into folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose setup something like:

```
/
- sources/
- docker-compose.yml
- Dockerfile
- .dockerignore
- many more files
```

The Dockerfile contains instructions including a COPY command of the sources.

Because of all the different tools, including multiple docker setups, I'd like to organise it a bit, by either moving all files to a folder:

```
/
- sources/
- docker/
- many more files
```

or leaving just the docker-compose.yml file outside of this folder:

```
/
- sources/
- docker/
- many more files
```

I'd like to do this because:

- It cleans up the project folder
- I currently have multiple docker setups in the project folder, moving them to seperate folders allows for a more clear and/or precise setup (e.g. multiple dockerignore files)

Currently I am running into some issues which do make sense, such as:

```
COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../sources/
```

Is it possible to achieve this setup? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the Dockerfile, you cannot access files that are outside the build context. In your case the build context is the directory containing the Dockerfile.

You can change the build context inside the composefile. 
Below is an example where the composefile is at the root and `Dockerfile` is under `docker` folder:

```
version: '3'

services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
```

In this case, inside the `Dockerfile` the file paths should be set relative to the context.

```
COPY sources sources
```

**For dockerignore**:

As specified in the docs for .dockerignore file:

> Before the docker CLI sends the context to the docker daemon, it looks for a file named .dockerignore in the **root directory of the context**

Thus you need to add the dockerignore file to the root of the context.

Comment: COPY is now working. Could you elaborate on whether i can add a .dockerignore in the docker folder, or will it look for one in the context (project folder)? Or can i specify it using some compose property?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that within the Dockerfile however you should be able to make it work using a .env file and pulling it in from there.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

You could try something like:

## .env

`SOURCE_PATH=../sources/`

## Dockerfile

`COPY ${SOURCE_PATH}/myfile /some/destination`